# Bounties on Meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, meta, bounty

Since we are always trying to improve our site, why don't we give people an incentive similar to the bounty system on the main site in order in order to give people the opportunity to work harder to improve our site's features?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?  Do you think posts on meta don't have enough visibility?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78264/cant-post-bounty-on-non-so-meta-sites#comment358243_78342

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I'm not worried about visibility, I just want people to have more incentive to answer the questions that are asked.

Comment: @AdamMosheh, what are some questions that are unanswered where answers could change things?  Most of the recent unanswered questions (with positive scores) are feature requests that would require the SE team to implement.  I'm still unclear on what behavior *from Mi Yodeyans* you would like to change.

Comment: "[S]imilar" how? If you mean that the bounty-awarder should forfeit main-site reputation points in favor of the bounty-recipient's main-site reputation, I think you should make that explicit in the question. Otherwise, I think you should explain (in the question) what you do mean.

Answer (score 4):

Child-metas (that is, meta sites like this one) are free of reputation gains. That's why, if you were to check out the "leaderboard" of this meta, the users are sorted by *activity* and not merely reputation. Sure, there's usually a pretty solid correlation between those two things, but not always.

Anyway, because metas are inherently rep-free, using bounties on this site wouldn't make any sense. Beyond that, it's your moderator team's duty to ensure that questions on meta that don't receive action from the community still receive administrative attention -- whether that's mine as a Community Manager, Jin's for design work, or a developer for features.

If it's about attention, then that's a different game. With the existence of the bulletin board, featured tags, and even the weekly chat event, there's plenty of opportunity for a meta post to get the attention it needs.

I'm [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)-ing this because it isn't something we plan on doing with child-metas ever, as it runs opposite of how we've built these.